# KQL Comparison to Find Changes

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer

How would compare values in column to see if it's changed for a unique item. For example, how would I modify a query to only display a record if the serial number changed for a specific unique device. In this case there is a new record each day for each DeviceID. An example is below. I'm a noob and have no idea where to start. If my question doesn't make sense or you need additional info please let me know. Thanks in advance.

MyInventory_CL
| mvexpand  parse_json(Health_s)
| project Date, DeviceID, ['Type'] = Health_s['Type'], ['XOLabel'] = Health_s['XOLabel'],['Serial'] = Health_s['XOSerial Number'], ['Placement'] = Health_s['XOPlNumber'], Status

Date            DeviceID            Type    Label            Serial                                    Placement  Status

03/10/24    FHDFKJSKFJ5 SSD HFM001TD3GX013N  25359_8549_2286_F168_9FFA_5625_3214_0085   0   On

03/10/24    EUXMSFSG78  SSD KBG40ZNS512G     30100_0090_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0157_C6FA   0   On

03/10/24    NMLWHQA98   SSD KBG40ZNS512G     H0100_0020_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0121_7017   0   On

03/10/24    WOOFTYUV36  SSD kBG50ZNS512G     Z0000_0030_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0389_1C04   0   On

03/10/24    SVDFKJSKF98 SSD HFM001TD3GX014N  L0000_0070_0000_0010_0008_0D05_000D_8ACB   0   On

03/09/24    FHDFKJSKFJ5 SSD HFM001TD3GX013N  5ACE4_2E10_2567_E6A5_2EE4_AC00_0000_0001   0   On

03/09/24    EUXMSFSG78  SSD KBG40ZNS512G     30100_0090_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0157_C6FA   0   On

03/09/24    NMLWHQA98   SSD KBG40ZNS512G     H0100_0020_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0121_7017   0   On

03/09/24    WOOFTYUV36  SSD kBG50ZNS512G     Z0000_0030_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0389_1C04   0   On

03/09/24    SVDFKJSKF98 SSD HFM001TD3GX014N  L0000_0070_0000_0010_0008_0D05_000D_8ACB   0   On

03/08/24    FHDFKJSKFJ5 SSD HFM001TD3GX013N  5ACE4_2E10_2567_E6A5_2EE4_AC00_0000_0001   0   On

03/08/24    EUXMSFSG78  SSD KBG40ZNS512G     30100_0090_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0157_C6FA   0   On

03/08/24    NMLWHQA98   SSD KBG40ZNS512G     H0100_0020_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0121_7017   0   On

03/08/24    WOOFTYUV36  SSD kBG50ZNS512G     Z0000_0030_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0389_1C04   0   On

03/08/24    SVDFKJSKF98 SSD HFM001TD3GX014N  L0000_0070_0000_0010_0008_0D05_000D_8ACB   0   On

Comment: Could you share what is your expected output?

Comment: Thank you. Using the example records above, I'd like to see only the records where the serial has changed. So with the data above, the first record with DeviceID FHDFKJSKFJ5 was changed on 3/10/24 to 25359_8549_2286_F168_9FFA_5625_3214_0085 from it's previous value on 3/8 and 3/9 of 5ACE4_2E10_2567_E6A5_2EE4_AC00_0000_0001. So I'd like to only return the record where the change occurred like this  

Date DeviceID Type Label Serial Placement Status

03/10/24 FHDFKJSKFJ5 SSD HFM001TD3GX013N 25359_8549_2286_F168_9FFA_5625_3214_0085 0 On

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> KQL Comparison to Find Changes

To compare column and find changes made in that column you can try with the below code.  In first `summarization`, it calculates the distinct count of serial numbers for each device `DeviceID` and filter it by where `distinctCountSerial > 1` now `inner` join is performed on the **DeviceID** and the second `summarization` is used for finding the maximum `Date` for each `DeviceID` and it again performs a `inner` join based on `Date` and `DeviceID` to get the expected result.

Click this [link](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8WWa2%2BbMBSGv%2BdX%2BFsSiUq2wWAydRLhkqy5bSK9rNNkEWJtbhOnIs62TvvxMwEaWq1Z9mEJSMDrg89j8Cuds%2BAKTJPZgnvgHMwTpU8tWkGieCfXXIklN0DAv4mUvws6YK0yIb8YYPr4wHdqmMz4Yidjnomkpt8vkpQvuVQdIKTScc3ZrKt4u%2FGpAfRR4VoYYusMmmcItg3QjPpBNLiIB9EFaWoZx0F%2B60cjCNE0MHs3EJnjfAgTk7iMEstlGFObRcimzI0ijxEbE2ZiZDEIaZ4F6tcnsmns44aXN6M4insOrWEH3Z4Fb8cxQbiXaxMiCHVWN7%2FA8kL90GQ0hBqHiMN8O%2FIOZI5Hw%2Bv%2BB8%2Fdh%2ByXSPwaEiPmQOQciLyeTKLpx8sr064x77s9UmfeliTzFaZJXYZ8aB3IjK%2FKLX32oc%2B21Npu6bCkOU9ctH2iDAaQ5E8Bo57f%2FSsXuv9kJeL5ocVwqGmY2A4LbY9oqcc8H%2B7%2BATqQe1wrFcyjWqlAHtdKBfMEVqInshI9gZXo8a1ET2Al%2Bp%2Bt1Pj8plGU2cYvsN4sl0kmfnIwF2slZKr81UaqomjqMpzmilWxVjHeBrPHpzKsk3z%2FyrM%2FJ3gLkI7frYQE90LOz4WUPAOt7ZeXa2iDlawn260oL%2Fx6Ccvkx7YHeEndl7VIqicZ9RkP2eqOp%2BpFoOgfyr6h6hdqfULVIvwG%2BBk9o58IAAA%3D) to check the query in Data Explorer.

**Query I tried with:**

```sql
let TableA = datatable(Date: datetime, DeviceID: string, Type: string, Label: string, Serial: string, Placement: int, Status: string)
[
    datetime(2024-03-10), 'FHDFKJSKFJ5', 'SSD', 'HFM001TD3GX013N', '25359_8549_2286_F168_9FFA_5625_3214_0085', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-10), 'EUXMSFSG78', 'SSD', 'KBG40ZNS512G', '30100_0090_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0157_C6FA', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-10), 'NMLWHQA98', 'SSD', 'KBG40ZNS512G', 'H0100_0020_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0121_7017', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-10), 'WOOFTYUV36', 'SSD', 'kBG50ZNS512G', 'Z0000_0030_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0389_1C04', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-10), 'SVDFKJSKF98', 'SSD', 'HFM001TD3GX014N', 'L0000_0070_0000_0010_0008_0D05_000D_8ACB', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-09), 'FHDFKJSKFJ5', 'SSD', 'HFM001TD3GX013N', '5ACE4_2E10_2567_E6A5_2EE4_AC00_0000_0001', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-09), 'EUXMSFSG78', 'SSD', 'KBG40ZNS512G', '30100_0090_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0157_C6FA', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-09), 'NMLWHQA98', 'SSD', 'KBG40ZNS512G', 'H0100_0020_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0121_7017', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-09), 'WOOFTYUV36', 'SSD', 'kBG50ZNS512G', 'Z0000_0030_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0389_1C04', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-09), 'SVDFKJSKF98', 'SSD', 'HFM001TD3GX014N', 'L0000_0070_0000_0010_0008_0D05_000D_8ACB', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-08), 'FHDFKJSKFJ5', 'SSD', 'HFM001TD3GX013N', '5ACE4_2E10_2567_E6A5_2EE4_AC00_0000_0001', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-08), 'EUXMSFSG78', 'SSD', 'KBG40ZNS512G', '30100_0090_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0157_C6FA', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-08), 'NMLWHQA98', 'SSD', 'KBG40ZNS512G', 'H0100_0020_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0121_7017', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-08), 'WOOFTYUV36', 'SSD', 'kBG50ZNS512G', 'Z0000_0030_0000_0000_8CE3_8E04_0389_1C04', 0, 'On',
    datetime(2024-03-08), 'SVDFKJSKF98', 'SSD', 'HFM001TD3GX014N', 'L0000_0070_0000_0010_0008_0D05_000D_8ACB', 0, 'On'
];
TableA
| summarize distinctCountSerial = count_distinct(Serial) by DeviceID
| where distinctCountSerial > 1
| join kind=inner (
    TableA
) on DeviceID
| summarize Date = max(Date) by DeviceID
| join kind=inner (
    TableA) on Date, DeviceID
| project Date, DeviceID, Type, Label, Serial, Placement, Status
```

**Output:**
[image]